# Is it possible to disable a panel in a React-bootstrap component?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm just getting started with React (and React-bootstrap components).  I have an accordion component working, but would like to have the option of disabling one or more of the child panels in the accordion control.  When disabled, I'd like the collapsed panel header to be rendered in a disabled state, and prevent expansion.  Is this possible?

Comment: It's not currently a possibility. Submit an issue to the repo, this is a worthwhile feature to add.

Comment: This answers my question.  Unfortunately I can't "accept" it as an answer since it's a comment..